# In example, How does order of call to notifyAll affect execution in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization

Going through the example of producer consumer problem here, http://java67.blogspot.com/2012/12/producer-consumer-problem-with-wait-and-notify-example.html

I see that notifyall is called after call to add, in producer class and before call to remove, in consumer class. Why is this so ?

What is the outcome if both are in the same order ?

Trying to understand synchronization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, [Banthar is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37688415/217324) (+1 from me). Regardless what order you put these in, the notification isn't going to get sent until after the notifying thread leaves the synchronized block. See [the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.2.2) (my emphasis added):

> There is no guarantee about which thread in the wait set is selected. This removal from the wait set enables u's resumption in a wait action. *Notice, however, that u's lock actions upon resumption cannot succeed until some time after t fully unlocks the monitor for m.*

When you're new to writing multithreaded Java code there are some issues to come to grips with. The example code you link to has not successfully dealt with some of these issues.

There is cooperative scheduling and pre-emptive scheduling: cooperative means the threads yield voluntarily at a time of their own choosing, pre-emptive means the scheduler can swap threads out at any time. Initially when Java came out some platforms were cooperative and others were pre-emptive, and code had to be written to run under both models if you wanted it to be cross-platform. For the purposes of understanding how to use wait and notify you should assume a pre-emptive model (because it's the prevalent model and it's also your worst case: you can't count on the threads to play nice).

Pre-emption can occur at any time, and the consequence is that if there's any interval between the time your thread checks something and the time it acts on the results of that check where your thread was not holding the lock, the result of the check is out of date and your action may be invalid. When the example code checks the size of the queue, then acquires the lock on the queue, in the time between that check and the time it takes the lock another thread may have acted and the size of the queue may have changed. That's why [Nicolas is giving you the advice to handle the locking like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37688731/217324):

```
synchronized (sharedQueue) {
    while (sharedQueue.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Queue is empty " + Thread.currentThread().getName()
                                + " is waiting , size: " + sharedQueue.size());
        sharedQueue.wait();
    }
}
```

What happens here is that the thread acquires the shared lock, and only then checks if the queue is empty. If the queue is empty there's nothing for the thread to do, so it releases the lock and goes dormant until notified. Then when it gets a notification it wakes up, reacquires the lock (it has to do this before exiting the wait method), and proceeds to check whether the queue is empty again at the top of the while loop. It has to check again (with the lock held) because it can't assume that the queue must be empty based on it having been notified: another thread could have barged in and acted in the time between when the waiting thread got notified and when it acquired the lock.

If the question is, why does the code call notifyAll and not notify, it's because notify only causes one thread to get picked, and that thread may be either a consumer or a producer and may not be able to effectively do anything, depending on the situation. So instead the code wakes up all the threads that are trying to acquire the lock and lets them fight it out. Not the most efficient thing but it works.

In summary:

- Acting based on checks made when the lock is not held is error-prone.
- Waiting threads release the lock, and there's no atomic linkage between notification and lock-reacquisition.
- You can't assume any particular thread gets chosen for a notification.

See [the Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html) for more examples.

Big picture, threads shouldn't be in charge of deciding what gets locked, because it isn't safe: introducing one badly-behaved thread could corrupt the data structure for everybody. Data structures should protect themselves from being corrupted by concurrent access. Wrap your queue in a threadsafe object which takes care of all the locking, waiting, and notifying. For example, if I make a bounded queue that encapsulates the list:

```
class MyBoundedQueue<T> {

    private final Object lock = new Object();
    private final int upperBound;

    public List mylist = new ArrayList();

    public MyBoundedQueue(int upperBound) {
        this.upperBound = upperBound;
    }

    public T take() throws InterruptedException  {
        synchronized(lock) {
            while (mylist.isEmpty()) {
                lock.wait();
            }
            lock.notifyAll();
            return mylist.remove(0);
        }
    }

    public void put(T t) throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized(lock) {
            while (mylist.size() == upperBound) {
                lock.wait();
            }
            mylist.add(t);
            lock.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

then the Consumer gets simpler (we can delete the consume method), becoming

```
class Consumer implements Runnable {
    private MyBoundedQueue<Integer> sharedQueue;

    public Consumer(MyBoundedQueue<Integer> sharedQueue) {
        this.sharedQueue = sharedQueue;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                System.out.println("consumed: " + sharedQueue.take());
                Thread.sleep(50L);                        
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

and likewise the Producer would look like

```
class Producer implements Runnable {
    private MyBoundedQueue<Integer> sharedQueue;

    public Producer(MyBoundedQueue<Integer> sharedQueue) {
        this.sharedQueue = sharedQueue;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                sharedQueue.put(i); 
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

This way the threads acquire the locks, but the data structure being accessed determines what needs to be locked. Also the BoundedQueue keeps the order you originally asked about, putting the remove last is there for convenience, to avoid needing to create a local variable to reference the element extracted from the list. The only significance is legibility, there's one less local variable name to have to read.

Comment: great answer.  your last paragraph is a bit confusing, as the distinction between "threads doing locking" and "objects doing locking" is kind of nebulous.  i assume you are trying to make a point about external locking vs internal locking (i.e. keeping the locking encapsulated within the data structure owner).

Comment: @jahlborn: thank you very much. i'll try to reword the last paragraph to make it clearer and add an example.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference. In both cases the thread being notified can continue execution only after the notifying thread has exited `synchronized` block. The order within `synchronized` block doesn't matter here.

Answer (score 1):

> I see that notifyall is called after call to add in producer class and
>   before call to remove in consumer class. Why is this so ?
>
> What is the outcome if both are in the same order ?

Actually it is done this way because I assume that the guy who wrote this (bad/incorrect/ugly...) code **wrongly** wanted to avoid the `Producer` to get into the `synchronized` block inside the while loop if the `Consumer` removes an element just before testing if the queue is full. It is the same idea for the `Consumer` that expects the queue to be not empty, if the `Producer` produces something just before `Consumer` tests if the queue is empty, it can avoid the `synchronized` block.

**NB:** The code in this blog post is totally incorrect a condition must always be tested in a `synchronized` block otherwise you can get race condition issues so instead of having this:

```
while (sharedQueue.isEmpty()) {
    synchronized (sharedQueue) {
        System.out.println("Queue is empty " + Thread.currentThread().getName()
                                + " is waiting , size: " + sharedQueue.size());
        sharedQueue.wait();
    }
}
```

The only valid code is:

```
synchronized (sharedQueue) {
    while (sharedQueue.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Queue is empty " + Thread.currentThread().getName()
                                + " is waiting , size: " + sharedQueue.size());
        sharedQueue.wait();
    }
}
```

So now as we know that the code is incorrect, you need to know that with the correct code we don't care the order anymore as we will test the condition in a `synchronized` block.

Comment: I consider your comments valuable Nicolas, Just trying to wrap my head around the answer.

Comment: if it is not clear don't hesitate to ask for clarification

Comment: hi Nicolas, no i didn't downvote, i did upvote Banthar because he directly answers the question. i do agree with your post and don't see how a downvote is warranted, it doesn't address the OP's question as directly though and may be a bit unclear to some readers. don't sweat the anonymous downvotes, they happen to everybody.